# Clarification of the definition of two dimensional motion of rigid body

Tags: definition, classical-mechanics

Our teacher gave the following definition:

Motion of rigid body is said to be two-dimensional if

1. Each particle of the rigid body moves in a plane parallel to some space-fixed plane.
2. The motion of particles of the rigid body which are in contact with the straight line perpendicular to the space-fixed plane are identical.

I do not understand either of the two points geometrically. Any explanation will be highly useful. Thank you.

Comment: If the body is rigid, 1. implies 2., and it does not make sense to say *the* straight line.

Comment: The motion of a rigid body can be decomposed into translation of the center-of-mass and rotation around the center. The conditions say that the rotation axis is orthogonal to the translation vector. The plane is then orthogonal to the rotation axis. "Perpendicular" is just another word for "orthogonal".

Comment: Assume WLOG that the fixed plane is $z=0$. Then every particle moves at constant $z$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if the fixed plane is the $xy$-plane, then the movement of a particle with initial coordinates $(x,y,z)$ must be such that only $x$ and $y$ change, but $z$ remains constant.

I cannot really parse the sentence under 2, but suppose that the following is meant: If two particles have same $x$ and $y$ coordinates at one point in time, but differ only in their $z$ coordinate, then this relation also holds for other points in time.

Note that for a non-deformable rigid body the second condition follows from the first, which already allows only translations parallel to the plane and rotations around axes perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: A rigid body is 3 dimensional.Then how can all the particles move in a single plane? If that happens, does it not becomes a lamina?

Comment: And the second point's explanation is still not clear to me

Comment: @Esha: it is not said that the plane is unique. Every particle moves in its own plane.

Comment: Okay, now I get the 1st point. Thanks